# Visual studio 2013, xamarin cannot find envdte.dte

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I am trying to create an android app with visual studio and I am having an issue with xamarin. When I try to load a project it says 'Missing service ENVDTE.DTE not found' What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so as it turns out the issue wasn't with visual studios. It turns out that updating xamarin fixed the issue. Somehow this didn't get installed correctly.